# Can I configure mIRC to alert me whenever a regex is matched?

Tags: irc, mirc

I would like to keep mIRC minimized, and get some noticeable alert whenever a text matching a regex (specifically \d+.\d+.\d+.\d+) appears on a channel. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Or switch to another IRC client that supports this, if mIRC does't.